# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table workers

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Not able to create table from Spring Boot in Oracle . Getting error org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table workers (uid number(10,0) not null, pwd varchar2(255), uname varchar2(255), primary key (uid))" via JDBC Statement

```
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table workers (uid number(10,0) not null, pwd varchar2(255), uname varchar2(255), primary key (uid))" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at com.lti.LoginFunctionalityApplication.main(LoginFunctionalityApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:630) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:564) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1151) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:771) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:299) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:498) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:112) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1011) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1531) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1311) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:2163) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:2118) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:328) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:637) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

POJO class

```
package com.lti.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Workers {
    
    @Id
    private int uid;
    
    private String uname;
    
    private String pwd;

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [uid=" + uid + ", uname=" + uname + ", pwd=" + pwd + "]";
    }
```

Comment: `uid` is reserved word in Oracle, you may potentially enclose it into quotes, however it is better to choose something different.

Answer (score 0):

if u using Oracle, just remove:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```